# async queue never triggers drain randomly

Tags: node.js, queue

I'm continuing to play around with nodejs. 
So below is a brief summary of my launch.js app

```
var counter = 0;
var queue = async.queue(function(objectWithVariousProperties, callback) {
    methodDoingVariousAsynchronousStuff(objectWithVariousProperties.link, function(err,result) 
        counter++;
        callback();
    });
}, 20);

queue.drain = function() {
    log.debug("Finished Queue", {
        "Objects processed" : counter
    });
};
//TO various iterations over several array and construct some object and then push them in the queue via 
queue.push(media_object)
```

My issue is that 80% of the time the process works.
the application launch via the shell command nodejs launch.js ,  process the queue, when queue is finished it displays the 'Finished Queue' then back to shell.

However, sometimes the drain event is never triggered but the application finished and  back to the shell without any exception. 
I inspected during several hours my code to find if there was a missing callback, but it does not seems so.

Any idea which can explain this strange random behaviour ?
Or any tools which would help to find the leaking code ?

As I said, sometimes, the queue process more than 10000 objects without any problem and sometimes when I launch it, it just does not trigger the drain event but the process stop (again without any exception or error or anything, just a normal stop)

I spent a couple of evenings trying to figure out why, so if you guys had any ideas it would be gladly welcomed.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you calling callback() with err when err is not undefined? If you aren't any errors will be swallowed and it will fail silently. I'd also log the arguments object in the drain function just in case, it doesn't seem to be documented that way but it might get called with an err object.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot give you an appropriate answer, but help you to debug your code instead. When node.js is not exiting, there's something left in the event loop.

This tool may help you to find it:
https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running

I'm pretty sure that your problem may belong to something in `methodDoingVariousAsynchronousStuff()` - the `async.queue` code looks almost fine.

Maybe something like an uncalled callback, unhandled error or an open network connection.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer. This seems a very interesting solution. However the plugin does work in my case, I'm facing the following issue already referenced https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running/issues/12. Do you have any alternative ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

As I see, you don't catch some error. Can you add to your code:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I hope it will help you find the problem. More info you can read in the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know this event. However, nothing appeared in the log....